# Remove text input from chatbox

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, chat

I'm trying to remove the textboxes from a JavaScript shoutbox. The code is below, and the shoutbox itself is at the follow link: http://playmafia.ga/killed/

```
function handleTag() {
  var inputArr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++)
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[i].src.match(/shoutbox.widget.me/)) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[i].scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}

function cookieSave() {
  var a = new Date();
  a = new Date(a.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12);
  document.cookie = '|hello|; expires=' + a.toGMTString() + ';';
}
cookieReaded = '';

function cookieRead() {
  if (document.cookie) {
    cookieConAll = document.cookie;
    cookieCon = cookieConAll.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookieCon.length; ++i) {
      cookieConLine = cookieCon[i];
      cookieConPart = cookieConLine.split('|');
      if (cookieConPart[1] == 'hello') {
        cookieReaded = 'i';
      }
    }
  }
}
xid = Math.random();
xid *= 10000000000000;
xid = Math.ceil(xid);
pushRef = document.referrer;
sumInp = pushRef + ' ' + document.URL;
allMac = /google\.|bing\.|yahoo\./i;
seaSou = new String(pushRef.match(allMac)).substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
if (pushRef.match(allMac)) {
  function getQ(strArg) {
    var _url = pushRef + "&";
    var regex = new RegExp("(\\?|\\&)" + strArg + "=([^\\&\\?]*)\\&", "gi");
    if (!regex.test(_url)) return "";
    var arr = regex.exec(_url);
    return (RegExp.$2);
  }
  pushKeys = getQ('q');
  if (pushKeys) {} else {
    pushKeys = getQ('p');
  }
  cleanKeys = pushKeys.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
  if (sumInp.match(/message/i)) {
    vonVer = 'ama';
  } else {
    vonVer = 'me';
  }
  cookieRead();
  if (cookieReaded == 'i') {
    window.onload = handleTag();
  } else {
    top.location.href = "https://shoutbox.widget.me/track.pl?von=" + vonVer + "&xid=" + xid + "&res=" + screen.width + "xxx" + screen.height + "&sea=" + seaSou + "&via=" + cleanKeys;
    cookieSave();
  }
}
```

The goal is to alter the chatbox so that no one can type, but they can see other messages appear from other links of the full, input-allowing, one.

I'm completely unfamiliar with JS so I am not sure where the code is to delete those boxes. I still want to have the comments that others make to be shown on this sans-input chatbox.

Here is the code in a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/amans/azuw5a95/1/

And if wondering or needed, the code is from this website but altered slightly: [shoutbox.widget.me](https://shoutbox.widget.me/)

Comment: Please be clear in your question

Comment: Okay, done, cleared it all up.